# CFThread Scope in debugger

Tags: debugging, coldfusion, scope, cfthread

Ok, trying to move 2 ldap and 2 sql queries into independent threads.
The original Adobe(?) CF 8 debugger with/for cfeclipse (not cf builder) does not show the supposed CFThread scope.

Can it be added to the CF8 debugger?

Does the CFBuilder 3 show the CFThread scope(s)?

(for the interim I am loading formation into the class (component / variables) scope but I really don't like this as I am using an application scoped class. )

Thanks.

Comment: "Does the CFBuilder 3 show the CFThread scope(s)?" SO is not a research service.

Comment: Well, that's interesting, but I still believe it is a valid question. The cfthread scope not being available in the debugger is causing the development cycle to take a bit longer than I would like, It seems reasonable to have it available, and I did not see the answer in SO or by google.

Comment: ok, well you can answer the question yourself by simply looking at CFB3.  It has an express version that is free and there is a trial.  If it doesn't do something you want, I would log a bug with Adobe.